# Generic Array (Vector) Class C++

Tags: c++, array, generics

I am a mathematician trying to learn how to become a better programmer in C++. I am currently now trying to write the main data structures from scratch. I have now completed a generic array class and I wanted to see if I was missing anything or if there is anything I can improve on.

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef Array_h
#define Array_h

#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Array {
private:
    int maxSize; // capacity of array
    int length;
    T *array;

public:
    Array(int size = 100);
    ~Array();
    void print() const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool isFull() const;
    int maxListSize() const;
    int listSize() const;
    T front() const;
    T back() const;
    void swap(T& x, T& y);
    void sort();
    int search(const T& item);
    void insert(int location, const T& item);
    void insertAtTop(const T& item);
    void deleteItem(const T& item);

    void operator=(const T& temp);
    T& operator[](int index) { return array[index];}
};

template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(int size) {
    if (size <= 0) {
        std::cout << "Size cannot be less than 0";

        maxSize = 100;
        array = new T[maxSize];
    }
    else {
        maxSize = size;
        length = 0;
        array = new T[maxSize];
    }

}

template <class T>
Array<T>::~Array() {
    delete[] array;
}

template <class T>
void Array<T>::operator=(const T &temp) {
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        array[i] = temp;
    }
}

template <class T>
void Array<T>::print() const {
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        std::cout << array[i] << "\t";
    }
}

template <class T>
bool Array<T>::isEmpty() const {
    return (length == 0);
}

template <class T>
bool Array<T>::isFull() const {
    return (length == maxSize);
}

template <class T>
int Array<T>::maxListSize() const {
    return maxSize;
}

template <class T>
int Array<T>::listSize() const {
    return length;
}

template <class T>
T Array<T>::front() const {
    return array[0];
}

template <class T>
T Array<T>::back() const {
    return array[length-1];
}

template <class T>
void Array<T>::swap(T& x, T& y) {
    T temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

template <class T>
void Array<T>::sort() {
    for(int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j < length - i - 1; j++) {
            if(array[j] > array[j-1]) {
                std::swap(array[j], array[j-1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

template <class T>
int Array<T>::search(const T& item) {
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(array[i] == item){
            return i;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

template <class T>
void Array<T>::insert(int location, const T& item) {
    if(length != maxSize) {
        int i = length;

        for(;i > location; i--) {
            array[i] = array[i-1];
        }
        array[i] = item;
        length++;
    }

}

template <class T>
void Array<T>::insertAtTop(const T& item) {
    if(length != maxSize) {
        array[length] = item;
        length++;
    }
}

template <class T>
void Array<T>::deleteItem(const T& item) {
    bool flag = false;
    int location = 0;
    for(;location < length; location++) {
        if(array[location] == item) {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(flag) {
        for(int i = location; i < length - 1; i++) {
            array[i] = array[i+1];
        }
        length--;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Element not found" << std::endl;
    }
}




#endif /* Array_h */
```

Here is the main file that tests some of the member functions (I have checked all and they work).

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Array.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Array<int> arr(5);
    arr.insertAtTop(2);
    arr.insertAtTop(4);
    arr.insertAtTop(6);
    arr.insertAtTop(8);
    std::cout<<"\n------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"---------------Displaying All contents of array---------------";
    std::cout<<"\n------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    arr.print();

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"-------------Inserting At Particular--------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    arr.insert(1, 12);
    arr.print();

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"----------------Deleting an Item-----------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    arr.deleteItem(12);
    arr.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing from scratch to learn about it is a worthy approach and I see that as the subject of presentations at the major conferences.

You should use the naming convention from the standard containers.  You wrote a `vector`, not an `array`.  You don’t `insertAtTop`, you `push_back`, etc.

---

```
T *array;
```

The style in C++ is to put the `*` or `&` with the *type*, not the identifier.  This is called out specifically near the beginning of Stroustrup’s first book, and is an intentional difference from C style.

[⧺C.149](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c149-use-unique_ptr-or-shared_ptr-to-avoid-forgetting-to-delete-objects-created-using-new) — no naked `new` or `delete`.

You should probably make this a `unique_ptr` as a drop-in replacement without otherwise changing the architecture.

---

```
Array(int size = 100);
```

Make that `explicit`.  Do you know why?

---

```
void print() const;
```

No, don’t make that a member function.  Provide a general way for users to access the elements.  Then a printing function can be written using the public API.

---

```
void swap(T& x, T& y);
```

Huh?  That is a (non-static) member, so why is it taking two additional parameters?

Skipping down to look at the implementation: you wrote it as a non-member.  So it should be a free (template) function swap.

As for how/whether it should be implemented, I’ll get back to that.

---

```
void sort();
```

No, just let the user do `std::sort` with your container or portions thereof.

```
int search(const T& item);
```

Again, can your implementation do better than a linear search?  Just let the user use `std::find` and `std::find_if` on your collection!

---

```
void operator=(const T& temp);
```

It is not normal to have a `void` return here.  You should `return *this;`.

**Edit:** OK, that’s not a copy assignment operator at all.  `void` is fine.  But the automatically-generated copy assignment code will not work right, as described next for the copy constructor.

---

Where is your copy constructor?  Your class will **seriously malfunction** if you write something like:

```
Array<int> arr(5);
  ⋮
Array<int> a2 = arr;
```

See [The rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

---

You should provide `move` semantics for efficient usage of the array object, and for faster insert/delete etc. when T is a complex type.

---

```
template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(int size) {
    if (size <= 0) {
        std::cout << "Size cannot be less than 0";

        maxSize = 100;
        array = new T[maxSize];
    }
    else {
        maxSize = size;
        length = 0;
        array = new T[maxSize];
    }

}
```

Don’t complain and use a different value.  Treat it as an error.

```
if (size <= 0)  throw std::invalid_argument ("Array size negative");
```

You are actually constructing the full number of elements of type T.  So your *length* is what?  How many of them you care about?  Normally, a collection will not construct elements that are not used.

---

```
template <class T>
Array<T>::~Array() {
    delete[] array;
}
```

If you used a `unique_ptr` like I suggested above, you would not need to write a destructor at all!  (And, it would not automatically generate a bad copy constructor!)

---

```
template <class T>
void Array<T>::operator=(const T &temp) {
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        array[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Hmm, that’s not an assignment operator at all.  It assigns a common value to all elements.

Just use `std::fill_n`.

---

The various trivial implementations should be in-line in the class definition.

---

```
template <class T>
void Array<T>::sort() {
    for(int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j < length - i - 1; j++) {
            if(array[j] > array[j-1]) {
                std::swap(array[j], array[j-1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A bubble sort?  Are you kidding?!

---

Your `front` and `back` functions don’t check for zero length.  You have a `deleteItem` function, so the user could delete all of them!

Speaking of `deleteItem`, you seem to duplicate the `find` code first.  Just use `find`!

---

insert functions silently do nothing if the container is full.  They should throw an exception.

Copying all the elements down one spot in a loop — can you find a std algorithm for that instead?

Comment: I am going to address each point you made and make the changes. After doing so should I make a new post?

Comment: Yes, feel free to post again with the new version.  You ought to link to this previous version when introducing the code.